# Animating points in a matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I have a bunch of 3D data relating to a shoulder (x3, y3, z3), an elbow(x2, y2, z2), and a wrist(x1, y1, z1). What i'd like to achieve is an animation which replicates the motion of the arm in a plot using matplotlib. Essentially, all I need to do is remove a set of three points on a 3D scatter plot and replace them on the same plot with the next set after a very short delay. I can't seem to find any questions which have covered this type of animation. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Current code below gives me the first set of points and that is all:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')


for i in range(len(x1)):

    wrist = ax.scatter(x1.pop(), y1.pop(), z1.pop(), s=20)
    elbow = ax.scatter(x2.pop(), y2.pop(), z2.pop(), s=20)
    shoulder = ax.scatter(x3.pop(), y3.pop(), z3.pop(), s=20)

    plt.show()
    time.sleep(0.01)

    wrist.remove()
    elbow.remove()
    shoulder.remove()
```

Comment: Replace the `scatter` calls with `plot3D`, passing `marker='o'` and `markersize=20` (and `linestyle='None' if you want to plot more than one point at the same time). Then follow the example [animation example code: simple_3danim.py](https://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/simple_3danim.html).